# a gstream plugin to generate video from bmp pics

Tags: plugins, gstreamer

I am now writing a gstreamer plugin as a source element.

I have several bmp pics. I want to generate a video from these pics.

Can anyone give me some guide or some tips. How can I write this gstreamer plugin

Answer (score 1):

You need to be using multifilesrc element. In order to use it your file names should be ordered like:

```
image001.bmp
image002.bmp
...
image099.bmp
...
```

an example  pipeline would be:

```
gst-launch-1.0 multifilesrc location="img.%03d.bmp" ! videoconvert ! <your favorite encoder here> ! avimux ! filesink location=my_video.avi
```